# 2 documents persist with a Testroute

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, async.js

I have received a task which has quite confusing english. Can someone explain what kind of question would interviewer was asking. Sorry about this silly question but I don't have a chance to contact and request clarification.

1. Initialize git repo - OK I UNDERSTOOD
2. Install Express, Mongoose in an easy way  - OK I UNDERSTOOD
3. Generate a project - OK I UNDERSTOOD
4. Generate 2 models and make 2 documents persist with a Testroute. (no reference among themselves)  - ????? persist with a Testroute & ref among themselves what does that mean ? Is that simple get route or post route ?
5. Create a route which brings you back a Json (combined out of the two documents)  - OK I UNDERSTOOD
6. Callback Hell: Think about, how you can get around the Callback Hell (from 5.) with async lib in an elegant way. Promises are not desirable.  - OK I UNDERSTOOD BUT I DIDN'T UNDERSTAND IF HE IS MENTIONING ASYNC/AWAIT OR ASYNC NPM PACKAGE

Answer (score 1):

. 4. Means to create 2 models eg. UserModel and BlogModel and to use Mongoose to persist a record into MongoDB via a `test route` eg. `POST /api/users`

. 6. If I were to guess it would be async await but it's unclear.

Comment: are there any special meaning of test route eg. POST . What is the meaning of "no reference among themselves"

Comment: Most likely don't do `user: {blog_id: 1}`. Don't have the documents reference themselves.

Comment: that makes sense